# default location of postgresql when installing through apt-get

Tags: apt, postgresql

When you install postgresql on 14.04, it sticks the main server program postgres at:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
```

the data directory where all the database clusters will be stored at:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

and the configuration file at:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

Now I can understand why postgresql.conf and other configuration files are stored in /etc/postgresql/9.3/main. After all, /etc is where configuration files are stored in a linux system.

However, why place the database storage area in /var/lib? I can understand /var, since that is the place for nonstatic data and databases are nonstatic. But why /var/lib in particular?

Further, I believe that /bin is for programs required for boot. /usr/bin is for programs included in the distribution. and /usr/local/bin should be for programs not included in the distribution but available for system-wide use. And thus since postgresql is intended for system-wide use, it should be available in /usr/local/bin. Yet, they place it in /usr/lib, which I have no idea why.

Why do I ask this question? Because without order and structure, it is difficult to remember the location of programs you use everyday.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, [`/var/lib/](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.8.html) is stated as (in italic the most important part):

> **5.8.1 Purpose**
>
> *This hierarchy holds state information pertaining to an application or
>   the system. State information is data that programs modify while they
>   run, and that pertains to one specific host.* Users must never need to
>   modify files in /var/lib to configure a package's operation.
>
> State information is generally used to preserve the condition of an
>   application (or a group of inter-related applications) between
>   invocations and between different instances of the same application.
>   State information should generally remain valid after a reboot, should
>   not be logging output, and should not be spooled data.
>
> An application (or a group of inter-related applications) must use a
>   subdirectory of /var/lib for its data. There is one
>   required subdirectory, /var/lib/misc, which is intended for state
>   files that don't need a subdirectory; the other subdirectories should
>   only be present if the application in question is included in the
>   distribution.
>
> /var/lib/ is the location that must be used for all distribution
>   packaging support. Different distributions may use different names, of
>   course.

In short: /var/lib/ is for data that is used locally.

So it makes perfect sense to put a database's data into /var/lib/{mysql|postgress}/ directory but... the FHS is a standard created mostly for use by *distributions*. As a user you are free to put your data wherever you want and it is mostly a matter of opinion.

---

You are misunderstanding the word "local". /usr/local/bin/ is not for system software but for your own software (basically anything with "local" in must never be touched by the system. As explained by FHS:

[/usr/local/](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.9.html)

> **4.9.1 Purpose**
>
> The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
>   installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
>   overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for
>   programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not
>   found in /usr. Locally installed software must be placed within
>   /usr/local rather than /usr unless it is being installed to replace or
>   upgrade software in /usr.

An executable installed from system software should never go to anything local.

---

Now for [/usr/lib/](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.7.html).

> **4.7.1 Purpose**
>
> /usr/lib includes object files, libraries, and internal binaries that
>   are not intended to be executed directly by users or shell
>   scripts. Applications may use a single subdirectory under
>   /usr/lib. If an application uses a subdirectory, all
>   architecture-dependent data exclusively used by the application must
>   be placed within that subdirectory.

postgressql is probably a daemon started at boot? If so it makes sense to put it here. You are not suppose to use the command yourself but start a service. The files in /usr/lib/ tend to have their own user and group and/or a daemon that restricts access to /var/lib (only mysqld can access /var/lib/mysql/ for instance; this will be the same for postgressql)