# System backup and PostgreSQL

Tags: 16.04, backup, postgresql

I would like to make backups of my whole `/` directory with `borgbackup`.  
However, since `PostgreSQL` has its own way to backup databases, I would use in this case the `SQL dump` method to create a snapshot of the database. 
Thus, when I perform my system backups, which directory am I expected to exclude from `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical PostgreSQL installation put all DB related content into `/var/lib/postgresql`. This is also the case in Ubutu, see this other question for example: [default location of postgresql when installing through apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617751/default-location-of-postgresql-when-installing-through-apt-get)

You can also see it if your database is running, in `ps` output the `postgres` process should have a `-D` flag followed by the path of the "data" directory.

If you start the `psql` client you can also use command `show data_directory;` to see it (if you are on the same host).

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database for even more ways to get this information.

Comment: Do you think I have to exclude from my system backup the whole `var/lib/postgresql` data directory or just the databases? I do not know if `pg_dumpall` performs on this directory or on single files.

Comment: You can exclude the whole directory **if** you do backup it another way (or just keep it in your backups, not a. trouble either even if restoring from it might not be possible). `pg_dump`and `pg_dumpall` do SQL level dumps, irrelevant to how the files are handled and spread out.